# Exchange 2010 - Single mailbox, Send from multiple accounts?

Tags: email, exchange-2010

Im new to Exchange 2010, but wanted to know if this was a new\existing feature that can be added?

Can I confirm that its still not possible to have a single mailbox and for a user (outlook) to send from multiple domains?

The only way to do this is to have multiple mailboxes\accounts in order to send from multiple domains?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, You are correct, in that you can only have users send out as separate addresses when setting up multiple mailboxes/accounts.  When using a single mailbox, it will always send out as the primary SMTP address of the mailbox.